# Windows 7 Default Aero for New Users

Tags: windows-7

How can I get the default Windows 7 Aero theme to work for all first time users?

The computer is a domain computer and whenever a new user logs in, Aero is disabled.

They can turn it on just by selecting the theme in control panel.

I've tried setting other themes as the default via registry, such as the USA themed one.  It changes the wallpaper and colors but not Aero transparency, it still uses the Windows 7 basic theme.

How can I ensure that Aero will be enabled by default for users?

Answer (score 1):

The ability to have a default profile and set it up for all users died with Windows XP. Microsoft never wanted that feature used.

**(1)** You can try Sysprepping the machines and see if you can set up Aero in Sysprep.

But otherwise, it is a User Setting and best (in my view) to let users set up as they wish, or set up as directed by a Corporate standard.

**(2)** You can try turning on Aero with a batch file.

You may be able to use the batch file from the Domain Setup.  There is a user are in the User Account where you can run a batch file.

[Win 7 Aero](https://thecustomizewindows.com/2011/07/restart-windows-7-aero-with-a-simple-batch-file/)

> @ECHO OFF echo. echo
> ********************************************************************* echo Restart Windows 7 AERO Program by TheCustomizeWindows.com echo.
> echo Do you Know that TheCustomizeWindows.com has 235+ Windows 7
> Tricks? echo. echo
> ********************************************************************* echo. echo. echo Wait, we will stop the AERO now, OK? echo. net stop
> uxsms echo. echo. echo Cool! Your System should have AERO running
> again after few seconds… echo. net start uxsms echo. echo. PAUSE

**(3)** You can also turn on Aero in the Windows 7 Registry

[Aero by registry](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/issues-enabling-windows-aero/4590087c-494c-43c3-8375-db0b6367bd60)

> Force Enable Aero in Windows 7
>
> 1. Click on Start and type regedit at run
> 2. Now Navigate to the following registry key:
>
> HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\DWM
>
> 3. In the right details pane, create following Three DWORD (32-bit value) entry
>
> UseMachineCheck, and set its value to 0.
>
> Blur, and set its value to 0.
>
> Animations, and set its value to 0.
>
> 4. Close Regedit
> 5. Click on Start and type CMD with administrative Priviliges
> 6. Now type following command
>
> Net Stop uxsms
>
> Net Start uxsms
>
> Above command will stop and start Desktop Window Manager Session
> Manager.

Comment: I've tried sysprepping it that way.  These machines are being prepared with MDT.  Aero was on and enabled in the Administrator account right before it rebooted to capture.  And I'm not allowed to create a GPO for this, so it has to be registry (no local group policy allowed either).

Comment: I added a registry setting in my answer for you . 3 methods in all

Comment: That registry setting is only for HKCU.  Is there any key in HKLM that would apply as a default for users for the DWM values?

Comment: s there any key in HKLM that would apply as a default for users for the DWM values    ......  Not for all users, just the individual user.  So you may need to get users to apply the Aero setting.

Answer (score 0):

I think I found the solution. Just run as administrator this bat script:

reg load HKLM\DefaultUser C:\Users\Default\NTUSER.DAT

reg add HKLM\Defaultuser\Software\Microsoft\Windows\DWM /v Composition /t REG_DWORD /d 1 /f

reg add HKLM\Defaultuser\Software\Microsoft\Windows\DWM /v CompositionPolicy /t REG_DWORD /d 2 /f

reg unload HKLM\DefaultUser

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).